# Updating a UIView's layer mid-animation

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, calayer

There's a neat little method in UIView that allows you to determine what its layer's class is, thus replacing it with a custom CALayer subclass that you control. There's only one problem with doing this, and that's animation.

If you animate the UIView's bounds, sure enough the layer animates its size. But it does so by simply rescaling its current appearance, which if you're going from a small size to a large one, looks hideously blurred and in entirely the wrong proportion.

What I'd like to know is, is it possible to have the UIView redraw the contents of its primary layer on every frame of the resizing animation? I guess you could use just CALayers, but that's extremely limiting when you consider that the rest of the iOS is heavily weighted towards working exclusively with UIViews.

Comment: Maybe you could use the method `drawRect:` of the `UIView`.

Comment: The problem with DrawRect is that you can only animate the elements of the view that Apple permits. What I want to do is combine animation of the view's bounds with animation of other elements - such as the shape of its corners for example - which are only really animatable using Core Animation.

Comment: I tried this out purely as an experiment and the results were the same. The view is redrawn once immediately that the animation begins, and the resulting image rescaled during the animation. There is no smooth transition.